# start google navigation and go back to my app android

Tags: android, google-maps

i'm trying to open google navigation from my app ans when clicking "back" to go back to my app.
i'm using this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + destination));
startActivity(intent);
```

but when pressing "back" the google navigation refreshing.

if i'm using `startActivityForResult(intent, 1);`
the google navigation not opening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not set a Flag in your intent, Try this working code:

```
Intent navigation = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
            Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&source=s_d" +
            "&saddr=xx.xxxxx,yy.yyyyy&daddr=xx.xxxxx,yy.yyyyy")); 
    navigation.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK&Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
   navigation.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
    startActivity(navigation);
```

Hope this would Help!!